# Spring boot REST API not returnning expect Json data

Tags: spring-boot, api

I just begin my first web application using Spring Boot, and I create the first project as well as the Database for this project. It used to fine to return the list of products with encapsulated datas that a product has. When I leave it for several Days and come back, the query api return instead of the products  themselves but links.

so when I type "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1" in the browser, it return this
[unexpected return JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGdYC.png).

Where it use to return something like

```
{
  "sku" : "BOOK-TECH-1000",
  "name" : "Crash Course in Python",
  "description" : "Learn Python at your own pace. The author explains how the technology works in easy-to-understand language. This book includes working examples that you can apply to your own projects. Purchase the book and get started today!",
  "unitPrice" : 14.99,
  "imageUrl" : "assets/images/products/books/book-1000.png",
  "active" : true,
  "unitsInStock" : 100,
  "dateCreated" : "2021-01-04T21:05:48.000+0000",
  "lastUpdated" : null,
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1"
    },
    "product" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1"
    },
    "category" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/products/1/category"
    }
  }
}
```

I dont know why the data informations are not return anymore, any suggestion?

[The return page of the GET query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYtdk.png)

[The DAO class I Created for the JPA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DT6i.png)

[The product class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gfO0.png)

[database data, which is what should be return in the result page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuP7e.png)

Product.java:

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
@Data
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

//join with Entity "ProductCategory". vise verse, many products to one product Category.
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
private ProductCategory category;

@Column(name = "sku")
private String sku;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "unit_price")
private BigDecimal unitPrice;

@Column(name = "image_url")
private String imageUrl;

@Column(name = "active")
private boolean active;

@Column(name = "units_in_stock")
private int unitsInStock;

@Column(name = "date_created")
@CreationTimestamp
private Date dateCreated;

@Column(name = "last_updated")
@UpdateTimestamp
private Date lastUpdated;
}
```

ProductRepository.java:

```
import com..Entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,   Long> {
}
```

Comment: Add your code here instead of an image of code

Comment: ProductRepository.java

package com.secureCoderX.ecommerce.Dao;

import com.secureCoderX.ecommerce.Entity.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:4200")
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced something similar due to lombok not working popery. Writing the getter and setter manually should work. In my case, adding lombok extension for vs code solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sensé to me now. 
What I had did is just import the project and deleting then rewriting the entire DAO and Entity class, then it worked. Did not notice if the Lombok worked or not, but I believe I felt the same case as you.

Comment: Thank you for providing the explanation!